# Issue with implementing "Login with Github" in iOS app

Tags: ios, github, oauth

I am trying to understand how I can authenticate my iOS app using github. I understand from the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/), that I need to implement this using `OAuth`.

I also understood that in my github profile, I need to register a new OAuth application, the form to do that looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand what info I have to provide for `Homepage URL` and `Authorization callback URL` as I am building an iOS app and not a webapp that is actually hosted on some server.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying FireBase. It has an infrastructure to enable [GitHub login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/github.html) specifically. Also, there are sufficient examples to create the app.